# Problema con FORM que busca usuario por ID

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un **bucar usuario por ID** entonces tengo la siguiente vista :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guardar Usuarios</title>
    <?php include '../static/bootstrap.php' ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once '../procedimientos/obtenerUsuarioById.php' ?>


    <?php include_once '../static/menu.php' ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="../procedimientos/obtenerUsuarioById.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>ID </label>
                        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="id"  placeholder="Introduce el ID del usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mt-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-info">Buscar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <!-- UNA VEZ SE HAYA BUSCADO -->

<?php if(isset($usuario)){ ?>
                    <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellidos</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Password</th>
                                <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                                <th>Pais</th>
                                <th>Fecha Registro</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Operaciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $usuario['id'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['nombre'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['apellidos'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['email'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['password'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['pais'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['fecha_registro'] ?></td>
                                    <td class="w-100 text-center">
                                        <?php 
                                        echo "<a class='btn btn-info' href='../vistas/guardar.php?id=".$usuario['id']."'>Editar</a>";
                                        echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='../procedimientos/eliminarUsuario.php?id=".$usuario['id']."'>Borrar</a>";
                                         ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                        </tbody>

                    </table>


<?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php include '../static/jquery.php' ?>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("nav li").removeClass("active");
          $("#buscar").addClass("active");

        });
    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el **fichero.php** al que llama :

```
 <?php 


    include_once 'conexion.php';

        if (isset($_GET['id']) or isset($_POST['id']) ) {

            if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."';";
            }
            else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."';";
            }


            //var_dump($sql);

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            //var_dump($result);



            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                $usuario = array(
                    "id"=>"",
                    "nombre"=>"",
                    "apellidos"=>"",
                    "email"=>"",
                    "password"=>"",
                    "pais"=>"",
                    "fecha_nacimiento"=>""
                );

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $usuario['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $usuario['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
                    $usuario['apellidos'] = $row['apellidos'];
                    $usuario['email'] = $row['email'];
                    //$usuario['password'] = $row['password'];
                    $usuario['pais'] = $row['pais'];
                    $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] = $row['fecha_nacimiento'];
                }


                var_dump($usuario);


            }


        }




     ?>
```

Lo que pretendo es que  si aun no se ha buscado el usuario (y por tanto no existe la variable `$usuario` que no muestre la tabla con el resultado de la **busqueda por id del form**). En cambio cuando lahay encontrado y por tanto exista la variable `$usuario` muestre la tabla.

El **var_dump()** me muestra que trae el usuario entero y bien, pero no me muestra la tabla, es como si se quedara en el **fichero.php al que esta llamando el form**

Comment: Podrías hacerlo mediante AJAX, validando primero que exista un usuarisi existe creas la tabla dinámicamente, si no existe mandas un mensaje de error o de aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tratar de que el archivo que incluye $usuario, llegue a la plantilla.

```
<?php

include_once 'conexion.php';

class SearchById
{
    private $id;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($connection, $id)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->id = (int) $id;
    }

    public function getSearch()    
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $this->getQuery());

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            return $this->getUser($result);
        }

        return $this->getUserEmpty();
    }

    protected function getUser($result)
    {
        $usuario = $this->getUserEmpty();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $usuario['id'] = $row['id'];
            $usuario['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
            $usuario['apellidos'] = $row['apellidos'];
            $usuario['email'] = $row['email'];
            $usuario['pais'] = $row['pais'];
            $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] = $row['fecha_nacimiento'];
        }

        return $usuario;
    }

    protected function getUserEmpty()
    {
        return array(
            "id" => "",
            "nombre" => "",
            "apellidos" => "",
            "email" => "",
            "password" => "",
            "pais" => "",
            "fecha_nacimiento" => ""
        );
    }

    protected function getQuery()
    {
        return "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '" . $this->id . "';";
    }
}

$search = new SearchById($con, $_GET['id'] ? $_POST['id'] : null);

// Usuario deberia llegar a la plantilla a partir de aquí
$usuario = $search->getSearch();
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta es muy interesante, revisa por qué es probable que el OP no esté programando con el paradigma POO

Comment: Gracias @Aprendiz

Comment: claro, ese es el problema, no estoy usado en este caso PHP POO. pero gracias por contestar